# What did I do wrong with my todo app?

Tags: angularjs

My todo app just doesn't work. It doesn't even display any pre-existing todo tasks on screen. Nor is it able to add or remove any items. 
All it renders is the input form and submit button. 
Why is that?  Please advise!

```
var app = angular.module('todoApp',[])
app.controller('TodoController',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.todos = [
        {task: 'Learn AngularJs', done: false},
{task:'Feed the dog', done: false},
{task: 'Water the cactus', done: true}]
    $scope.addTodo = function(){
        $scope.todos.push({task: $scope.todoText, done: false});
        $scope.todoText ='';
        console.log($scope.todos);
    }
    $scope.removeTodo = function(){
        var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
        $scope.todos = [];
        angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
           if (!todo.done) $scope.todos.push(todo);
        });
    }

}])

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="todo.js"></script>
        <style>
            .done-true{
                text-decoration: line-through;
                color: grey;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div ng-controller="TodoController as todoList">
                <ul class="unstyled">
                        <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                            <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.task}}</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form ng-submit="todoList.addTodo()">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Add a new todo" ng-model="todoList.todoText">
                            <input type="button" type="submit" value="add">
                        </form>
                    <button ng-click="todoList.removeTodo()">Delete All</button>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have seen any errors in the console?

Comment: no it didnt throw any error

Answer (score 1):

You are using **MVVM** method in your context so if you use **controllerAs** you need to use **VM** varibale is a scope in the controller instead of $scope variable. If you have any issues about MVC and MVVM please go through the **reference link**

http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns/understanding-mvc-mvp-and-mvvm-design-patterns

http://www.meritsolutions.com/mobile-development/mvvm-architectural-pattern-angularjs/

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp',[])

app.controller('TodoController',['$scope', function($scope){
    var vm = this;
    vm.todos = [
        {task: 'Learn AngularJs', done: false},
{task:'Feed the dog', done: false},
{task: 'Water the cactus', done: true}]
    vm.addTodo = function(){
        if(vm.todoText)
        vm.todos.push({task: vm.todoText, done: false});
       vm.todoText ='';
        console.log(vm.todos);
    }
    vm.removeTodo = function(){
        var oldTodos = vm.todos;
        vm.todos = [];
        angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
           if (!todo.done) vm.todos.push(todo);
        });
    }

}])
```

```css
.done-true{
                text-decoration: line-through;
                color: grey;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="todoApp" ng-controller="TodoController as todoList">
                <ul class="unstyled">
                        <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                            <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.task}}</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form >
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Add a new todo" ng-model="todoList.todoText">
                            <input type="button" type="button" value="add" ng-click="todoList.addTodo()">
                        </form>
                    <button ng-click="todoList.removeTodo()">Delete All</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `todoList.` while accessing variables and methods.. 
So your code should look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="todo.js"></script>
        <style>
            .done-true{
                text-decoration: line-through;
                color: grey;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div ng-controller="TodoController">
                <ul class="unstyled">
                        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                            <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.task}}</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Add a new todo" ng-model="todoText">
                            <input type="button" ng-click="addTodo()" type="submit" value="add">
                     </form>
                    <button ng-click="todoList.removeTodo()">Delete All</button>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```